# How to add one piece of text and/or graphic across all slides in a presentation in Keynote app?

Tags: keynote

Is there a way to add text (or graphic) to all slides in a presentation in Keynote?

In a professional presentation, we often need to include a company logo and a copyright claim across all the slides in a presentation.

I would rather not have to copy-paste over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a different slide layout for each and every page on your Keynote presentation, you can just add the picture or text necessary to the slide layouts of the presentation.

To do that:

1. Go to View->Edit Slide Layouts from the menu bar when your Keynote presentation is open to get to the slide layouts.
2. Add the picture or text necessary to the layouts used in the presentation (there might be quite a few layouts visible if you used one of the existing Keynote templates but people usually use only a few of the layouts in a template).
3. Return to your presentation by selecting View->Exit Slide Layouts from the menu bar.

See the "[Add and edit slide layouts in Keynote on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/guide/keynote/tan7a2b69972/mac)" Apple support article for more.